# How to calculate the numpy.sum(axis=1) and numpy.angle

Tags: python, numpy

From the following test code, it is easy to understand the `x.sum()` and `x.sum(axis=0)`.

**Question 1:**
How to calculate `each value` in `x.sum(axis=1)`?

**Question 2:**
What does the value of `np.angle(x, deg=True)` mean, and how `np.angle` works for an `array`?

test code:

```
import numpy as np
x = np.arange(27).reshape((3,3,3))
x
```

output:

```
array([[[ 0,  1,  2],
        [ 3,  4,  5],
        [ 6,  7,  8]],

       [[ 9, 10, 11],
        [12, 13, 14],
        [15, 16, 17]],

       [[18, 19, 20],
        [21, 22, 23],
        [24, 25, 26]]])
```

test code:

```
x.sum()
```

output:

```
351
```

test code:

```
x.sum(axis=0)
```

output:

```
array([[27, 30, 33],
       [36, 39, 42],
       [45, 48, 51]])
```

test code:

```
x.sum(axis=1)
```

output:

```
array([[ 9, 12, 15],
       [36, 39, 42],
       [63, 66, 69]])
```

test code:

```
x.sum(axis=2)
```

output:

```
array([[ 3, 12, 21],
       [30, 39, 48],
       [57, 66, 75]])
```

test code:

```
y = np.angle(x, deg=True)
y
```

output:

```
array([[[0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0.]],

       [[0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0.]],

       [[0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0.]]])
```

Comment: what is your desired output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can think of a 3D array, like the one you have shown here as having the following dimensions (batch, rows, columns).

When using `x.sum()` you get the result of the sum of all of the values in the 3D array.

When using `x.sum(axis=0)` you get an array with shape (1,3,3) where you've performed a straight forward matrix addition operation such as:

[image: matrix]

When using `x.sum(axis=1)` you get an array with shape (1,3,3) where you've performed a row-wise addition. In the image above it would be like adding a + b, c + d, w +x, and y + z.

Finally, When using `x.sum(axis=2)` you get an array with shape (1,3,3) where you've performed a column-wise addition. In the image above it would be like adding a + c, b + d, w + y, and x + z.

In your last example, this keeps returning 0s because you providing an integer, not a complex number. An example of a complex number would be 2i or 2i + 1.

See this example from the numby docs:

```
>>> np.angle([1.0, 1.0j, 1+1j])               # in radians
array([ 0.        ,  1.57079633,  0.78539816])
>>> np.angle(1+1j, deg=True)                  # in degrees
45.0
```

visit the numpy docs for more info : https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.angle.html